# How to retrieve data from the previous entry/row on a select statement?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, google-bigquery, window-functions

How to retrieve data from the previous entry/row on a select statement?

Here is some data:
[image]

I want to retrieve facID, read_date, and previous date for each row based on facID.

[image]

I think using window function can help here like below code:

```
select factory_id,read_date from (
    select factory_id,read_date,
    rank() over (partition by factory_id order by read_date) as RN
    from Table order by factory_id,read_date
) a
```

But not sure how to write a code to retrieve the previous date.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag):

```
select 
  factory_id,
  read_date,
  lag(read_date) over (partition by factory_id order by read_date) as last_read_date
from Table
order by factory_id,read_date
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey. I found this error when I tried to run it on BQ. `Number of arguments does not match for analytic function LAG. Supported signature: LAG(ANY, [INT64], [ANY]) at [4:3]` Do you know what Arguments I have to use in Lag()?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: Btw, is there anyway to find out the difference time between read_data and lag(read_data) ? Should I use the time_diff function or there is a better function?

Comment: For example, Using something like `TIME_DIFF(read_date, (lag(read_date) over (partition by factory_id order by read_date)), HOUR) as difference`

Comment: Yes, TIME_DIFF and TIMESTAMP_DIFF is the way to go.